# Is it possible to find the location of the suspending co_await expression from an std::coroutine_handle?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

The `co_await` operator makes the current coroutine suspended, and the compiler must save where the coroutine should continue execution when it's resumed, so there is a location information somewhere. Is it possible to obtain this location information and convert it to file and line numbers to help debugging coroutines and trace back asynchronous calls?
I guess if such feature exists, it must be compiler specific, I'm interested in both GCC and MSVC compilers.

My current workaround is having an ugly `AWAIT` macro that's declared like this in debug builds:

```
#define AWAIT(x) (co_await (x).passLocation(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__))
```

Where `x` is the return type of a coroutine that has a `passLocation` method which passes the info into the promise, then returns `*this`. And I'm using `AWAIT(x)` instead of `co_await x`.

If there is a way to let obtain location infromation from the handle, then I can avoid using this hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of evaluating the `co_await x;` expression calls `e.await_ready()`, where `e` is either `x` or a derivative of `x`. The `await_ready` function is called with no parameters. However, the overload of `await_ready` *can* have default parameters; it just needs to be callable with no parameters.

So you can use the standard C++20 mechanism for capturing program location: `std::source_location::current()` as a default parameter to `await_ready`.

However, this is part of the awaitable type, *not* a part of the promise. If you need to get this to the promise, then it needs to go into `await_suspend`, which gets a `coroutine_handle<P>` to the promise object via the expression `e.await_suspend(h)`, where `h` is a `coroutine_handle<P>`.

That being said, such direct coupling between an awaitable and a promise isn't the most ideal situation. `coroutine_handle<>` erases the type of the promise, so you have to explicitly have your `await_suspend` overload use `coroutine_handle<P>`, where `P` is the particular promise type of your current function. You can have a different overload for different promise types (or `<>` if you don't care):

```
  auto await_suspend(coroutine_promise<P> h, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
  {
    h.promise().suspend_location(loc);
    //Usual stuff.
  }
```

You would need a generic overload (using `coroutine_promise<>`) to handle promises that aren't of type `P`.

Comment: TIL std::source_location. That was what I needed.